# GridX set class for row (based on row data)

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojo.gridx

Is it possible for GridX to set the class for the given **row**, based on the data in that row?

I'd like to show with special color the rows that were added or changed. That information will be stored in the object as a special field.

As for now, I've found only, how to individualize rendering of **cells** (using decorator, or overwriting `setCellValue`).

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer here

http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/formatter-o-decoration-in-GridX-td4000793.html

Cell 7 is checked for the value 'ok'.

```
dojo.connect(grid.body, 'onAfterRow', function(row){
    var r = row.data();
    if(r[6] !== 'ok'){
        domClass.remove(row.node(), "gridxRowOdd");
        row.node().style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
});
```

or if empty cells should not get coloring:

```
dojo.connect(grid.body, 'onAfterRow', function(row){ 
var r = row.data(); 
var node = row.node(); 
if(r[6] !== 'ok'){ 
    var cells = dojo.query('.gridxCell', node); 
    var c = cells.length; 

    for(var i = 0; i < c; i++){ 
        cells[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red'; 
    } 
} 

} 
});
```

Because dojo.connect is old and somewhat? deprecated. Use aspect.after:

```
aspect.after(grid.body, 'onAfterRow', lang.hitch(this, function (row) {
var item = row.rawData();
if (item[6] !== '') {
   domClass.remove(row.node(), "gridxRowOdd");
   row.node().style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
}), true);
```